# Angular - show cumulative array building in template

Tags: angular, rxjs

How do I show an array building in an Angular template as it builds in values?

```
const timer = interval(1000);
const array = [1,2,4,6,9,10,8,9,6,5]
let newArray = []
this.count$ = timer.pipe(
    map(i => newArray.push(array[i])),
  );


<h2>{{ count$ | async }}</h2>
```

Only shows the last emitted value. I want to see [1], then [1,2] then [1,2,4] etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `zip` and `scan`:

```
this.count$ = zip(timer, array).pipe(
  map(([i, value]) => value),
  scan((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], [])
);
```

`zip` will ensure that the timer only emits as many times as there are values in the `array`.

`map` will then get rid of the value from `timer` and just take the value from `array`.

`scan` will then accumulate the values into an array as they are emitted.

Comment: I'm getting a typescript error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Comment: Do you have more details? Stackblitz? Which part is the error coming from?

Comment: Thanks, I got it working for me by typing the brackets at the end, so [] as number[]. I leave a stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ge5xzu?file=src/app/app.component.ts